# MEMORY_MANAGEMENT BSOD while playing Overwatch

Tags: windows-10, bsod, gaming

I was wondering what's causing this problem and how I can fix it.

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 10.0.21349.1004 AMD64
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


Loading Dump File [C:\WINDOWS\MEMORY.DMP]
Kernel Bitmap Dump File: Kernel address space is available, User address space may not be available.


************* Path validation summary **************
Response                         Time (ms)     Location
Deferred                                       srv*
Symbol search path is: srv*
Executable search path is: 
Windows 10 Kernel Version 19041 MP (12 procs) Free x64
Product: WinNt, suite: TerminalServer SingleUserTS
Edition build lab: 19041.1.amd64fre.vb_release.191206-1406
Machine Name:
Kernel base = 0xfffff800`20c00000 PsLoadedModuleList = 0xfffff800`2182a230
Debug session time: Fri Jun 11 09:06:17.029 2021 (UTC - 7:00)
System Uptime: 0 days 9:23:38.882
Loading Kernel Symbols
...............................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
.............................................
Loading User Symbols
PEB is paged out (Peb.Ldr = 00000030`22fc3018).  Type ".hh dbgerr001" for details
Loading unloaded module list
.................
For analysis of this file, run !analyze -v
nt!KeBugCheckEx:
fffff800`20ff6c20 48894c2408      mov     qword ptr [rsp+8],rcx ss:0018:ffffd80c`c1a7d2d0=000000000000001a
10: kd> !analyze -v
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

MEMORY_MANAGEMENT (1a)
    # Any other values for parameter 1 must be individually examined.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000041792, A corrupt PTE has been detected. Parameter 2 contains the address of
    the PTE. Parameters 3/4 contain the low/high parts of the PTE.
Arg2: ffff930114c69f08
Arg3: ff00065a00000000
Arg4: 0000000000000000

Debugging Details:
------------------


KEY_VALUES_STRING: 1

    Key  : Analysis.CPU.mSec
    Value: 7467

    Key  : Analysis.DebugAnalysisManager
    Value: Create

    Key  : Analysis.Elapsed.mSec
    Value: 7861

    Key  : Analysis.Init.CPU.mSec
    Value: 2139

    Key  : Analysis.Init.Elapsed.mSec
    Value: 12983

    Key  : Analysis.Memory.CommitPeak.Mb
    Value: 78

    Key  : MemoryManagement.PFN
    Value: 65a00000

    Key  : WER.OS.Branch
    Value: vb_release

    Key  : WER.OS.Timestamp
    Value: 2019-12-06T14:06:00Z

    Key  : WER.OS.Version
    Value: 10.0.19041.1


BUGCHECK_CODE:  1a

BUGCHECK_P1: 41792

BUGCHECK_P2: ffff930114c69f08

BUGCHECK_P3: ff00065a00000000

BUGCHECK_P4: 0

BLACKBOXBSD: 1 (!blackboxbsd)


BLACKBOXNTFS: 1 (!blackboxntfs)


BLACKBOXPNP: 1 (!blackboxpnp)


BLACKBOXWINLOGON: 1

PROCESS_NAME:  Overwatch.exe

STACK_TEXT:  
ffffd80c`c1a7d2c8 fffff800`20e4423a     : 00000000`0000001a 00000000`00041792 ffff9301`14c69f08 ff00065a`00000000 : nt!KeBugCheckEx
ffffd80c`c1a7d2d0 fffff800`20e42a6f     : ffff9603`1607f700 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000002 00000000`00000000 : nt!MiDeleteVa+0x153a
ffffd80c`c1a7d3d0 fffff800`20e12c10     : 00000000`00000001 ffffd80c`00000000 ffff9603`1607f550 ffff9603`0f3e3080 : nt!MiDeletePagablePteRange+0x48f
ffffd80c`c1a7d6e0 fffff800`20e52277     : 00000000`2298d3ff 00000000`00000000 ffff9603`00000000 fffff800`00000000 : nt!MiDeleteVad+0x360
ffffd80c`c1a7d7f0 fffff800`211f906c     : ffffd80c`00000000 00000000`00000000 ffffd80c`c1a7d950 00000229`8d3e0000 : nt!MiFreeVadRange+0xa3
ffffd80c`c1a7d850 fffff800`211f8b45     : 00000000`00000000 ffff9603`0df7c1c0 ffffd80c`c1a7da18 00000000`00000000 : nt!MmFreeVirtualMemory+0x4ec
ffffd80c`c1a7d9a0 fffff800`210085b5     : ffff9603`0f3e3080 ffff9603`14695080 00000000`00000000 ffff9603`00000000 : nt!NtFreeVirtualMemory+0x95
ffffd80c`c1a7da00 00007ff8`1a20d1e4     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiSystemServiceCopyEnd+0x25
00000030`248fd6e8 00000000`00000000     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : 0x00007ff8`1a20d1e4


SYMBOL_NAME:  nt!MiDeleteVa+153a

MODULE_NAME: nt

STACK_COMMAND:  .thread ; .cxr ; kb

IMAGE_NAME:  ntkrnlmp.exe

BUCKET_ID_FUNC_OFFSET:  153a

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  0x1a_41792_nt!MiDeleteVa

OS_VERSION:  10.0.19041.1

BUILDLAB_STR:  vb_release

OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x64

OSNAME:  Windows 10

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {ad6dfca3-101b-35a8-d6e1-12de9ecbc1f5}

Followup:     MachineOwner
---------
```

**Update:** Just got this I hope this helps identify the problem also I checked my ram which its fine actually

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 10.0.21349.1004 AMD64
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


Loading Dump File [C:\WINDOWS\MEMORY.DMP]
Kernel Bitmap Dump File: Kernel address space is available, User address space may not be available.


************* Path validation summary **************
Response                         Time (ms)     Location
Deferred                                       srv*
Symbol search path is: srv*
Executable search path is: 
Windows 10 Kernel Version 19041 MP (12 procs) Free x64
Product: WinNt, suite: TerminalServer SingleUserTS
Edition build lab: 19041.1.amd64fre.vb_release.191206-1406
Machine Name:
Kernel base = 0xfffff804`55000000 PsLoadedModuleList = 0xfffff804`55c2a230
Debug session time: Sat Jun 19 05:21:12.568 2021 (UTC - 7:00)
System Uptime: 0 days 3:43:50.421
Loading Kernel Symbols
...............................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
.............................................
Loading User Symbols
PEB is paged out (Peb.Ldr = 00000037`e21e2018).  Type ".hh dbgerr001" for details
Loading unloaded module list
.................
For analysis of this file, run !analyze -v
nt!KeBugCheckEx:
fffff804`553f6c20 48894c2408      mov     qword ptr [rsp+8],rcx ss:ffffec08`6d547860=000000000000001a
11: kd> !analyze -v
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

MEMORY_MANAGEMENT (1a)
    # Any other values for parameter 1 must be individually examined.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000061941, The subtype of the BugCheck.
Arg2: 0000016f22f50000
Arg3: 000000000000000f
Arg4: ffffec086d547a00

Debugging Details:
------------------


KEY_VALUES_STRING: 1

    Key  : Analysis.CPU.mSec
    Value: 3265

    Key  : Analysis.DebugAnalysisManager
    Value: Create

    Key  : Analysis.Elapsed.mSec
    Value: 12903

    Key  : Analysis.Init.CPU.mSec
    Value: 327

    Key  : Analysis.Init.Elapsed.mSec
    Value: 8751

    Key  : Analysis.Memory.CommitPeak.Mb
    Value: 80

    Key  : WER.OS.Branch
    Value: vb_release

    Key  : WER.OS.Timestamp
    Value: 2019-12-06T14:06:00Z

    Key  : WER.OS.Version
    Value: 10.0.19041.1


BUGCHECK_CODE:  1a

BUGCHECK_P1: 61941

BUGCHECK_P2: 16f22f50000

BUGCHECK_P3: f

BUGCHECK_P4: ffffec086d547a00

PROCESS_NAME:  msedge.exe

STACK_TEXT:  
ffffec08`6d547858 fffff804`55487c62     : 00000000`0000001a 00000000`00061941 0000016f`22f50000 00000000`0000000f : nt!KeBugCheckEx
ffffec08`6d547860 fffff804`55404d5e     : ffffdc0c`874d9000 00000000`00000000 ffffec08`6d547a80 00000000`00000000 : nt!MmAccessFault+0x15fe52
ffffec08`6d547a00 00007ff9`8e56b44e     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiPageFault+0x35e
00000037`e71ff250 00000000`00000000     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : 0x00007ff9`8e56b44e


MODULE_NAME: hardware

IMAGE_NAME:  hardware_ram

STACK_COMMAND:  .thread ; .cxr ; kb

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  0x1a_61941_PAGE_TABLE_RESERVED_BITS_SET_IMAGE_hardware_ram

OS_VERSION:  10.0.19041.1

BUILDLAB_STR:  vb_release

OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x64

OSNAME:  Windows 10

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {c6e5c6cf-692e-7852-5dc5-b74944540fc0}

Followup:     MachineOwner
---------
```

I have an Asus GL504GW if more specs needed I will add them

Comment: I would upgrade your Windows installation to 21H1.  Be sure you undo any overclocking you have enabled.

Comment: @Ramhound I am on that version also I never overclocked my pc is that cause overheating?

Comment: `OS_VERSION:  10.0.19041.1` did you install the 21H1 enablement package by chance?

Comment: @Ramhound Yes I have is there any problem with that?

Comment: I suggest checking your memory for errors. You can use the Windows-integrated memory diagnostic tool to do so. When you start it, make sure to open the options (F1) and select the extended test, with at least 2 runs. The test will take quite some time.

Comment: @DanielB I actually have done that as I mentioned I checked the ram